# Block displaying one parent and many children nodes using only Views 3 Drupal 7?

Tags: views

I'm trying to generate a block that looks like this in Drupal 7 Views 3:

---

- Parent Node (fields)
  - Child Node 1 (fields)
  - Child Node 2 (fields)
  - Child Node 3 (fields)
  - ...

---

Parent node is a different content type than child node. For the time being, I've added a matching taxonomy field to the two content types. So to potentially establish a relationship, this value would be the same.

What is the best way to achieve this? It seems like a simple enough goal that Views should be able to handle. I prefer to thoroughly understand the core software w/ Views, before I blindly install a bunch of modules that I may not need.

Comment: More information is needed. Tagging the nodes with the same term does not setup a parent/child relationship.  Are they child pages because of their position in the menu structure?

Comment: I'm not sure what information you would like. I haven't done anything yet, aside from set a taxonomy term field for each content type to establish a foreign key, but I haven't attempted to utilize this in any way yet - sorry to cause confusion. I'm basically just looking for a best-practice, or even some general advice as to how to accomplish this.

Comment: Well first off, you need one of two things.  They have to be designated as child pages by adding them to the menu, or you need to add a node reference field (http://drupal.org/project/references) so you can relate the children pages to there parent.  I would start there.

Comment: Let's take a step back - I'm trying to create a data model for an event calendar. It has a few parent fields: calendar title, calendar description, and events - where events is an array of events each with their own fields. I'm trying to put this in terms of Drupal, and display it in a block.

Comment: I've installed References and created the parent child relationships, but how do I utilize this in Views?

Comment: Do you want this block to show only on the parent pages, or available anywhere?

Comment: Available anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I've achieved the desired output by creating a vocabulary of taxonomy terms which is essentially just a flat list of foreign keys. There is no semantic representation of a hierarchy here.

**NOTE:** This is a different example than the event calendar I described in the comments of my initial post, however the data model is the same.

- Parent content type (Rich Menu) contains this taxonomy term field, in this example called "Menu".
- Child content type (Rich Menu Item) also contains the "Menu" taxonomy term field.
- If Rich Menu Item is a child of Rich Menu, the two term fields are set to match. **NOTE:** I wonder if this idea can be simplified using node references (References module) instead of taxonomy.

Then I created a new block view called "Rich Section Menu". This block will display the parent content type, Rich Menu, filtered by the taxonomy term from the field "Menu" (value = Section). Create an attachment to be displayed after the block which will render a list of children from the Rich Menu Item content type. The child content type will also be filtered by the Menu term field (value = Section). **NOTE:** Adding the relational term field to the list of filters is only necessary if you expect to have multiple parent/child relationships that share the same content types.

Tried to post screenshots of my Views configuration for clarity, but my reputation isn't high enough.

This achieves the output I desire, however it's a bit simplistic. I would prefer to create a semantically correct parent/child hierarchy using taxonomy or node references, and have Views render that output in a single block, without an attachment, with support for children more than one level deep.

So this works, but is there any way that I can do it better?